# USB Webcam works on 2 out of 3 machines?

Tags: usb, webcam

I have a USB webcam (actually an [Eachine ROTG01 FPV reciever](http://www.eachine.com/Eachine-ROTG01-UVC-OTG-5_8G-150CH-Full-Channel-FPV-Receiver-For-Android-Mobile-Phone-Smartphone-p-843.html) but it presents itself as a generic USB webcam) that when I connect to my Windows 10 tower does absolutely nothing - no new devices are detected at all, never-mind being unrecognized. When I plug it in to my Windows 10 laptop, it works fine and is detected as a USB2.0 camera. When I connect it to a raspberry Pi it does the same, but my tower fails to even detect a USB device has been plugged in. What could possibly cause such a strange issue?

For what it's worth, I have tried both the front panel and motherboard USB connectors and I have unplugged a port with a currently working device in it and replaced it with this camera, still completely undetected as being plugged in.

Comment: Is it [this model](http://www.eachine.com/Eachine-ROTG01-UVC-OTG-5_8G-150CH-Full-Channel-FPV-Receiver-For-Android-Mobile-Phone-Smartphone-p-843.html)? According to the specs, it's only designed to work with Android devices. What operating systems are your tower and laptop running?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer

Comment: @freginold yes, but its effectively just a generic USB webcam. The tower is Windows 10 and the laptop is Windows 10. There are a lot of videos online of people viewing this through webcam software on windows, even the built-in camera app. I think this is something specific to the tower...

Comment: How do you connect your receiver to "my Windows tower"? And to "my Windows laptop"? Details of the cables please.

Comment: @AliChen It's just a USB connection.. Like a standard USB webcam... as described. Ignore the fact that it does not look like a standard webcam. For all intents and purposes it presents itself via usb as a generic USB2.0 webcam.

Comment: Have you tried checking for any USB driver updates?

Comment: It doesn't look as a standard webcam. The seller title says "...OTG...", implying that it could be a host, or a device. Standard webcams are devices, not hosts. The role changing is determined by cable types. That's why I am asking you how do you connect the "OTG webcam" (with some mini-USB receptacle) to your hosts, are "tower" and "laptop" cables different, or the cable is the same.

Comment: No, it's not a host. It acts as a standard USB webcam.